# Spark Column Function for Python

Tags: apache-spark

I've read a few articles on spark "column functions". They appear to be standard UDF functions that accept a column parameter and return a column type. e.g.

```
def removeAllWhitespace(col: Column): Column = {
  regexp_replace(col, "\\s+", "")
}
```

In one of the articles it states: "UDFs are a black box for the Spark engine whereas functions that take a Column argument and return a Column are not a black box for Spark."

The example above is in Scala. Can the same thing be done in python with the same performance benefits?

Comment: Please explain the down vote so I can edit/clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compose objects from [`pyspark.sql.functions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

def remove_all_whitespace(col):
    return regexp_replace(col, "\\s+", "")
```

Usage:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(["fo oo  oo   ooo"], "string")
df.select(remove_all_whitespace("value"))
```